# Having trouble taking user inputs and forming arrays

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops

I need to take user inputs and and post them to a two dimensional array. This is what I have so far:

```
System.out.print("How many students? ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    int col = input;
    int row = 5;
    String[][] y = new String[col][row];
    for (col = 0; col < y.length; col++) {
        for(row = 0; row < y[col].length; row++){
        int n = col + 1;
        System.out.println("Enter the name and grades of student " + n);
        y[col][row] = scan.next();
    }System.out.println();
    }
    for(row = 0; row< y.length; row++){
           for(col = 0 ;col< y[row].length; col++){ 
                 System.out.println(y[row][col]);
           } 
          System.out.println(); 
       }
```

The only problem is that it asks the same question 5 times over before moving on to the next student. Do I stay on this same path? Or would it be easier to scrap it and go at it with a different approach?

Comment: What is the intent of the 5 rows per student - what data about students is intended to be stored here? The current code asks for the same data 5 times, which seems redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this loop of yours goes trough **each student**,

```
for (col = 0; col < y.length; col++)
```

and this loop of yours goes trough **each note** and asks to input them,

```
for(row = 0; row < y[col].length; row++)
```

so, it's logical that you want to ask the user **only one time** to input the note, saying that you only need to ask it **each time you iterate a student** in the array, simply change this:

```
for (col = 0; col < y.length; col++) {
    for(row = 0; row < y[col].length; row++){
        int n = col + 1;
        System.out.println("Enter the name and grades of student " + n); //you are asking each time you iterate a note
        y[col][row] = scan.next();
    }System.out.println();
```

to this:

```
for (col = 0; col < y.length; col++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name and grades of student " + col); //you are asking each time you iterate a student
    for(row = 0; row < y[col].length; row++){
        int n = col + 1;
        y[col][row] = scan.next();
    }System.out.println();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is that you can ask all the details for a particular student and then proceed for the next student rather than asking the same question for each student.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.print("How many students? ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = scan.nextInt();
int col = input;
int row = 5;
String[][] y = new String[col][row];
for (col = 0; col < y.length; col++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name and grades of student " + col);
    for(row = 0; row < y[col].length; row++){
    int n = col + 1;
    y[col][row] = scan.next();
}System.out.println();
}
for(row = 0; row< y.length; row++){
       for(col = 0 ;col< y[row].length; col++){ 
             System.out.println(y[row][col]);
       } 
      System.out.println(); 
   }
```

This will ask to enter the details once per student.

Answer (score 0):

> if you like to accept name and 4 grades input then this is your
>   code,else elaborate your problem

```
for (col = 0; col < y.length; col++) {
> 
>         int n = col + 1;
>     
>       System.out.println("Enter the name and grades of student " + n);
>     
>         for(row = 0; row < y[col].length; row++){
>           
>         y[col][row] = scan.next();
>     }System.out.println();
>     }
```